# Azure Service Fabric : Use stateless service to store data into stateful service (c# programming)

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

Objective: Want to create a product with some entities in a `stateless` service and the created product should get stored in a `stateful` service (`IReliableDictionary`)

```
// Task done: I am working with Azure Service Fabric. Firstly, I created a 
// stateful service which does the job of AddProduct and GetAllProducts and the 
// data is stored in IReliableDictionary. For this I have declared, and passed 
// the object in a constructor.

private readonly IReliableStateManager _stateManager;
public ServiceFabricRepository(IReliableStateManager stateManager)
{
   _stateManager = stateManager;
}
```

If I am adding a product within a `stateful` service the product is being added into the database (`IReliableDictionary`). This is tested and its working.

The next task, what I did is add a new service (`stateless`) in the solution. The `stateless` should create a product with some entities (`Id`, `Name`). The product created should be added in my database (`stateful` service)

Problem: I am able to create the product with some entities but the product is not being added in my database, because it is asking me to create an instance of `IReliableStateManager` in the `stateless` service and the `stateManager` is always `null`.

How to create an instance of `IReliableStateManager` in a `stateless` service 
since `IReliableStateManager` is provided by the `stateful` service inheritance 
hierarchy. I am creating an instance of my repository in a `stateless` service

```
//(stateManager is never assigned to and will always have its dafult value null) 
private static IReliableStateManager stateManager; 
private ServiceFabricRepository = new ServiceFabricRepository(stateManager)
```

I have done some search and found out that `stateful` service is used for data storage( Example interfaces: `AddProduct` or `GetProduct`) and `stateless Web Api` is used to expose the interfaces of `stateful` service using service remoting or `Http` for communication between the services. But was unable to find any example for my scenario.

Will be very helpful for any help or suggestions

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 2):

You do not use IReliableStateManager directly in Stateless service, rather call Stateful service from Stateless and pass object needs to be saved.

For example:
Create service proxy of stateful service in stateless service and call its method:

```
IProductService = ServiceProxy.Create<IProductService>(new Uri("fabric:/SfSample/ProductService"), new ServicePartitionKey(0));
var newProduct = new Product()
{
    Name = product.Name,
    Id = product.Id
};
await _productService.AddProduct(newProduct);
```

And Stateful service:

```
public class ProductService : StatefulService, IProductService
    {

        public async Task AddProduct(Product product)
        {
            var products = await StateManager.GetOrAddAsync<IReliableDictionary<Guid, Product>>("products");

            using (var tx = StateManager.CreateTransaction())
            {
                await products.AddOrUpdateAsync(tx, product.Id, product, (id, value) => product);

                await tx.CommitAsync();
            }
        }
...........
}
```

Comment: The stateless service is not frontend web API, so do I need to use Service Remoting. Also unable to use IProductService directly in the stateless service ( private IProductService productService) because it says there is no implicit conversion.

Comment: As these are independent services, Service Remoting has to be used to communicate. And for IProductService you have to create proxy something like this : IProductService = ServiceProxy.Create<IProductService>(new Uri("fabric:/SfSample/ProductService"), new ServicePartitionKey(0));